# Plume Sim in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used plume sim in Player/Stage - now I want to use it in ROS. However, I am not able to get much of a clue about installing it and using it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9045/plume-sim-in-ros/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/plumesim
points you at the repository for the ROS version of plumesim:
http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/unstable/simulator_plumesim/plumesim

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on 2016-04-05**:
Both of these link are broken now.  Are there any updated repositories or wiki pages?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-05**:
Apparently [jmerdich/isr-uc-ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_plumesim](https://github.com/jmerdich/isr-uc-ros-pkg/tree/master/stacks/simulator_plumesim/trunk) is a googlecode export of the package mentioned by @tfoote. Can't comment on its state though, and appears to be a `rosbuild` pkg still.

**Comment by [jbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/23668/jbourne/) on 2016-04-06**:
I am fairly new to ROS, so I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but would I be able to use this package on ROS indigo or jade if it is a rosbuild pkg?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-06**:
`rosbuild` pkgs can be build on recent ROS releases, yes. But it could very well be that the code itself does no longer compile on Indigo or Jade.